# Use of XSD unique the identity constraint on attributes that are not required

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd-1.1

I have an XSD where the same attribute (e.g. **FullStartOrder**), of type **xs:float**, is used on multiple elements, but not all elements.  The attribute (e.g. **FullStartOrder**) is not required by the XSD.  There is an edit requirement is to make sure the same floating point number is not used in all elements where the (e.g. **FullStartOrder**) attribute is supplied.

My understanding is that the identity constraint “**key**” can’t be used because “**key**” requires the “identity constraint Selector” and “identity constraint Field” to exist.  Which does not met this use case because the attribute is optional.  Therefore the “unique identity constraint” is being used.
The identity constraint is on the root element because the root element is the scope that defines uniqueness.  But each of the following “identity constraint Selectors” has some type of error.  It is also my understanding the XPath rules in a identity constraint support the full XPath spec in version 1.1.

### Test 1

When

```
<xs:unique name="NoDuplicateFullStartOrder">
    <xs:selector xpath="utils:."/>
    <xs:field xpath="@FullStartOrder"/>
</xs:unique>
```

is tried there are no errors in the XSD or a sample XML.

#### Failure 1

But there is no error when duplicate values exist.

### Test 1.1

When

```
<xs:unique name="NoDuplicateFullStartOrder">
    <xs:selector xpath="utils:."/>
    <xs:field xpath="utils:@FullStartOrder"/>
</xs:unique>
```

is tried the following error is produced during a validate check of the XSD.

#### Failure 1.1

The value 'utils:@FullStartOrder' of attribute 'xpath' of identity constraint definition 'utils:NoDuplicateFullStartOrder' is not a valid restricted XPath expression.

### Test 2

When

```
<xs:unique name="NoDuplicateFullStartOrder">
    <xs:selector xpath="utils://"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@FullStartOrder"/>
</xs:unique>
```

is tried the following error is produced during a validate check of the XSD.

#### Failure 2

The value '//' of attribute '//' of identity constraint definition 'NoDuplicateFullStartOrder' is not a valid restricted XPath expression.

### Test 3

When

```
<xs:unique name="NoDuplicateFullStartOrder">
    <xs:selector xpath="utils:."/>
    <xs:field xpath="@FullStartOrder"/>
</xs:unique>
```

is tried the following error is produced during a validate check of the XSD.

#### Failure 3

The value '//' of attribute '//' of identity constraint definition 'NoDuplicateFullStartOrder' is not a valid restricted XPath expression.

I have even tried adding (not shown in below XSD snippet.) but then id not work either.

```
xmlns:utils=http://www.mycompany.com/utils
targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/utils" 
elementFormDefault="qualified"
```

How should the below identity constraint be specified to meet the requirements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="ENTER_NAME_OF_ROOT_ELEMENT_HERE">
.
.
.
        <xs:unique name="NoDuplicateFullStartOrder">
            <xs:selector xpath="."/>
            <xs:field xpath="@FullStartOrder"/>
        </xs:unique>
.
.
.
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

## Sample invalid document.

### All FullStartOrder attributes have the same value, 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2020 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)-->
<utils:Utils xmlns:utils="http://www.bcbst.com/utils" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bcbst.com/utils utils_properties_1_1_1.xsd">
.
.
.
    <utils:Hosts>
        <utils:Host utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="asynchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
            <utils:Host_FQDN>anwas42.bcbst.com</utils:Host_FQDN>
.
.
.
        </utils:Host>
        <utils:Host utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="synchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Host>
        <utils:Host utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="asynchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Host>
    </utils:Hosts>
    <utils:Deployment_Managers>
        <utils:Deployment_Manager utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="synchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Deployment_Manager>
        <utils:Deployment_Manager utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="asynchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Deployment_Manager>
        <utils:Deployment_Manager utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="synchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Deployment_Manager>
    </utils:Deployment_Managers>
    <utils:Node_Agents>
        <utils:Node_Agent utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="asynchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Node_Agent>
        <utils:Node_Agent utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="synchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Node_Agent>
        <utils:Node_Agent utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="asynchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Node_Agent>
    </utils:Node_Agents>
    <utils:Clusters>
        <utils:Cluster utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="synchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
            </utils:Cluster_Member>
.
.
.
        </utils:Cluster>
    </utils:Clusters>
.
.
.
</utils:Utils>
```

## Sample valid document

### All FullStartOrder attributes have different values

FullStopOrder, CellStartOrder and CellStopOrder don't have any constraints, but the will once FullStartOrder constraint working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2020 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)-->
<utils:Utils xmlns:utils="http://www.bcbst.com/utils" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bcbst.com/utils utils_properties_1_1_1.xsd">
.
.
.
    <utils:Hosts>
        <utils:Host utils:FullStartOrder="1.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="asynchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
            <utils:Host_FQDN>anwas42.bcbst.com</utils:Host_FQDN>
.
.
.
        </utils:Host>
        <utils:Host utils:FullStartOrder="2.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="synchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Host>
        <utils:Host utils:FullStartOrder="3.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="asynchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Host>
    </utils:Hosts>
    <utils:Deployment_Managers>
        <utils:Deployment_Manager utils:FullStartOrder="4.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="synchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Deployment_Manager>
        <utils:Deployment_Manager utils:FullStartOrder="5.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="asynchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Deployment_Manager>
        <utils:Deployment_Manager utils:FullStartOrder="6.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="synchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Deployment_Manager>
    </utils:Deployment_Managers>
    <utils:Node_Agents>
        <utils:Node_Agent utils:FullStartOrder="7.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="asynchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Node_Agent>
        <utils:Node_Agent utils:FullStartOrder="8.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="synchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Node_Agent>
        <utils:Node_Agent utils:FullStartOrder="9.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="asynchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
        </utils:Node_Agent>
    </utils:Node_Agents>
    <utils:Clusters>
        <utils:Cluster utils:FullStartOrder="10.0" utils:FullStopOrder="1.0" utils:InvokeType="synchronous" utils:CellStartOrder="1.0" utils:CellStopOrder="1.0">
.
.
.
            </utils:Cluster_Member>
.
.
.
        </utils:Cluster>
    </utils:Clusters>
.
.
.
</utils:Utils>
```

## XSD

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding of identity constraints causes me to put the identity
>   constraint on the root element.

It should go on the element that scopes the uniqueness. If every X within a Y has to have a unique value for Z, then the constraint should go on the Y element; the selector should select X relative to Y, and the field should select Z relative to X.

`But each of the following “identity constraint Selectors” has some type of error.`

Be specific: tell us what you did and tell us how it failed.

> It is also my understanding the XPath rules in a identity constraint
>   support the full XPath spec in version 1.1.

No, that's not correct. Identity constraints still use a restricted XPath subset. You can use full XPath in assertions and conditional type assignment, but not in identity constraints. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#coss-identity-constraint

Comment: In this case "the element that scopes the uniqueness" is the root element.  I have updated the question to reflect this.

“Be specific: tell us what you did and tell us how it failed.” I have updated the question to make each thing that was tried more clear.

Comment: It would be useful to show at least one example of a valid and invalid document.

Comment: Sample valid and invalid XML added to original post.  XSD diagram also added.

Comment: @ Michael Kay:  Does time permit for you to look at the latest update to the question as per your request?  Please.

Comment: Well for starters, your attribute `utils:FullStartOrder` is in a namespace, whereas your XPath expressions are looking for a no-namespace attribute `FullStartOrder`.

Comment: Even with the namespace added still not working.  Tests 1, 1.1, 2 and 3 all still fail.

Comment: StackOverflow is designed with a simple question/answer format, it really doesn't work well as a vehicle for collaborative and incremental debugging. I found a bug in your code; that answers the question; if you still can't get it working, you should raise a new question.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the bug you found?

Comment: I did so: you failed to include a namespace prefix in the XPath expression.

Comment: I made the correction that Micheal Kay stated on Dec 5 at 16:11.  As can be seen from my comment on Dec 6 at 17:16  there was no change.  The error remains.I would be very grateful if you would stick with me on this issue.

Comment: I have made it clear that SO doesn't work this way. If you've fixed a bug that I identified and you still have a problem, then you need to raise a new question.